# What is the correct CSS file path for localised HTML pages?

Tags: html, css

I have a multi-region website, in raw HTML. So if you're in USA, Australia or elsewhere, you should be served localised content. Currently I have all my html files on the top level, with CSS files in a folder (css). I'm trying to organise the content so that all USA content is in a USA folder (the same for Australia, etc).

If the CSS/JS etc files are in a separate folder, it seems like I can't use a relative URL structure.

So instead of, for example, `<link href="css/minify-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">`, what file path should I put, so that the USA html files can find the CSS path?

Sorry for the noob question, still learning HTML/CSS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question might be a case of working out the *relative path* to the CSS file from each page.

For example, if your CSS files are all in /css/ (as you say), but now you've moved USA pages into /USA/, then, in USA/index.html (etc) your CSS declaration should be like this:

```
<link href="../css/minify-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

The "../" means "go up a directory". And then, it goes into the /css/ directory.

Comment: Thanks Vexen! That worked! The pages are rendering correctly now!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I could help. Could you "mark my answer as correct" so it is easy for others to see what worked?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `/` to replace the entire pathname of the base URL or `//` to replace everything from the hostname onwards. See [Retative URLs](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a different content for different regions, but you should use common styling/scripting path `css/` and `js/` for all regions.